# Dynamically get/select a div inside a div based on parent and child classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below structure:

```
<div class="fc-event lifeguard">
     <div class="fc-event-inner">
     </div>
</div>
```

Within a javascript function, I am using this:

```
$('.lifeguard').find('.fc-event-time')
```

To get all the elements that I want to modify the css of. I need to be able to get the div inside of these objects also. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple selector to target both :

```
$('.lifeguard').find('.fc-event-time, .fc-event-time div');
//gets elements .fc-event-time and along with all child divs in it
```

Comment: This appears to give both objects using: $('.lifeguard').find('.fc-event-time, .fc-event-inner div');  I just want to get the second object so I can do something like .css on just the fc-event-inner div portion.

Comment: Actually, if used correctly it works. Sorry about that. Thank you very much for your assistance!